# Reason for "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/openejb/loader/OpenEJBInstance"

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception, ejb, openejb

I am learning J2EE with this tuto : http://tahe.developpez.com/java/javaee/ and I am trying to make my fisrt client server app. But whenI run my client application I have

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2516)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:204)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy330.calculerFeuilleSalaire(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1641)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:456)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:37)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:29)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInstantiator.newInstance(DefaultInstantiator.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:86)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:172)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.produce(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:98)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl._createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1631)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/openejb/loader/OpenEJBInstance
    at org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory.init(LocalInitialContextFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory.init(LocalInitialContextFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(LocalInitialContextFactory.java:40)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at metier.Metier.<init>(Metier.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:79)
    ... 36 more
```

This is my pom.xml in the part on the server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>< project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>mv-pam-ejb-metier-doa-eclipselink</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<name>mv-pam-ejb-metier-doa-eclipselink</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>openejb-loader</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency> 
  <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId> 
  <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId> 
  <version>4.0.0</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId> 
  <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId> 
  <version>2.0.3</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
  <groupId>mysql</groupId> 
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
  <version>5.1.6</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId> 
  <artifactId>swing-layout</artifactId> 
  <version>1.0.3</version> 
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So my question is why and in which case could I have such exeptions?

Comment: Looks like the `openejb-loader.jar` is missing in your classpath

Comment: I already have openejb-loader is my classpath but it seems that it is not reached. I don't know why....

Comment: What is your applicationserver? in which folder is the openejb-loader.jar and in which folder is the jar containing the core classes?

Comment: I am prety new in J2EE and I don't realy know what all you ask means but I am using Netbeans and maven. So my .jar file should be right placed, isn't it? My server in Glassfish4.

Comment: You are deploying a war file? Is that right? If yes is the `openejb-loader.jar` and the jar contains the `org.apache.openejb.core` classes in you war?

Comment: Yes: In the interface of Netbeans it appears with the others jar files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line you want Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/openejb/loader/OpenEJBInstance

There is no ejb-loader in the runtime of your application server.
Try to put that in you pom:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>openejb-loader</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If you are running this in the IDE make sure that it is creating your war correctly, as commented.
Or ignore some information in the tutorial and search for java ee jboss, You do not need this dependencies with jboss application server you just need the API for compilation proposes.